# How can we convert numerical data to labeled data and make a prediction?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I understand how to encode labeled data into numerical data, using any of several techniques, including One-hot Encoding, Label Encoding, Ordinal Encoding, etc. I am wondering how to convert the numerical data back into labeled data. Here's a simple example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load Library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier,AdaBoostClassifier,GradientBoostingClassifier# Step1: Create data set


# Define the headers since the data does not have any
headers = ["symboling", "normalized_losses", "make", "fuel_type", "aspiration",
           "num_doors", "body_style", "drive_wheels", "engine_location",
           "wheel_base", "length", "width", "height", "curb_weight",
           "engine_type", "num_cylinders", "engine_size", "fuel_system",
           "bore", "stroke", "compression_ratio", "horsepower", "peak_rpm",
           "city_mpg", "highway_mpg", "price"]

# Read in the CSV file and convert "?" to NaN
df = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data",
                  header=None, names=headers, na_values="?" )
df.head()

df.columns

df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
df_fin


X = df_fin[['symboling', 'normalized_losses', 'make', 'fuel_type', 'aspiration',
       'num_doors', 'body_style', 'drive_wheels', 'engine_location',
       'wheel_base', 'length', 'width', 'height', 'curb_weight', 'engine_type',
       'num_cylinders', 'engine_size', 'fuel_system', 'bore', 'stroke',
       'compression_ratio', 'horsepower', 'peak_rpm']]
y = df_fin['city_mpg']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# Fit a Decision Tree model
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Now, how can I make a prediction of the target variable (dependent variable) based on the independent variables???

Something like this should work, I think, but it doesn't...

```
clf.predict([[2,164,'audi','gas','std','four','sedan','fwd','front',99.8,176.6,66.2,54.3,2337,'ohc','four',109,'mpfi',3.19,3.4,10,102,5500,24,30,13950,]])
```

If we leave numerics as numerics, and put quotes around labels, I would like to predict the dependent variable, but I can't, because of the labeled data. If the data was all numerics, and this was a regression problem, it would work!! My question is, how can we convert categorical codes back into numerical labeled data, and make a prediction??

Comment: But that's not the error you get from your code. If you're going to use DataFrames with this model, you need to pass in a DataFrame just like your original, but with one row. For example, you fit the model with 23 features but that example you're passing in has 26 -- obviously that won't work.

As for your question about encoding -- if you use `sklearn`'s encoders, you can use the `inverse_transform()` method on the encoder to go back to string labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data you want to use to predict the target variable needs to be in the same format as the data used for training the model.

I recommend encoding categorical data using e.g. `sklearn OneHotEncoder` (for one hot encoding, but there is also i.a. `OrdinalEncoder` and `LabelEncoder`). This allows you to first `fit()` the preprocessor on your categorical data which you can then later use to `transform()` the data you wish to predict.

Example using one hot encoding:

```py
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({"car_make": ["audi", "bmw", "bmw", "renault"],
"car_country": ["DE", "DE", "DE", "FR"], "car_age": [1, 3, 1, 5]})

categorical_cols = ["car_make", "car_country"]
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(df[categorical_cols]) # fitting the transformer on our categorical data

X_enc = enc.transform(df[categorical_cols]).toarray() # this returns a numpy array with the encoded values
```

You can use the `get_feature_names_out()` method on your fitted encoder to get an array of column names. Example building on the above:

```py
df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(X_enc, columns=enc.get_feature_names_out())
print(df_encoded)
   car_make_audi  car_make_bmw  car_make_renault  car_country_DE  car_country_FR
0            1.0           0.0               0.0             1.0             0.0
1            0.0           1.0               0.0             1.0             0.0
2            0.0           1.0               0.0             1.0             0.0
3            0.0           0.0               1.0             0.0             1.0

# getting our original values:
df_orig = enc.inverse_transform(X_enc)
print(df_orig)
[['audi' 'DE']
 ['bmw' 'DE']
 ['bmw' 'DE']
 ['renault' 'FR']]
```

If you then want to transform the values back to their original values you can use `inverse_transform` on your encoded data to return them.

I recommend looking at the docs for more details and use cases: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder

Using sklearn preprocessors will save you a lot of trouble down the road!

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but what if I pass in this: 'audi' 'DE'. Will I see this: '1'. Where is the 'clf.predict' outcome?

Comment: Very nice, but how do you make a prediction? This doesn't work...

X_enc.predict([['audi', 'DE', 1]])